# Cómo puedo obtener un único objeto de room?

Tags: android, kotlin, room

Estoy tratando de obtener un objeto en particular de la base de datos room dado su título pero cuando intento que esto suceda en el fragmento, observando el view model, no tengo manera de acceder a las variables del objeto. El método que estoy tratando de usar es retrieveMovie pero el observer muestra que it=List! y entonces no puedo obtener los campos como el título, el poste de la película entre otros para poder ponerlos en mi view.

Intenté acceder a la película con su index 0 (it[0].title) pero cuando voy a clicker en otra película, la app se cierra y me da el error: 'java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0'
Alguna idea de cómo puedo lograr esto?

La parte del fragmento:

```
if(arguments != null){
            val titleString = arguments?.getString("Title")

            //observe viewmodel
            if (titleString != null) {
                mMoviesViewModel.retrieveMovie(titleString).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { movie ->
                    itemTextTitle.text = movie.title //this doesn't work
                })
            }
        } else {
            //display error message if arguments are null
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error loading content", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

El view model de room:

```
class MoviesViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val readAllData: LiveData<List<Movies>>
    private val repository: MoviesRepository

    init {
        val moviesDao = MoviesDatabase.getDatabase(application).moviesDao()
        repository = MoviesRepository(moviesDao)
        readAllData = repository.readAllData
    }

    fun addMovie(movie: Movies) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.addMovie(movie)
        }
    }

    fun movieExists(id: Int): Boolean{
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            repository.movieExists(id)
        }
        return true
    }

    fun retrieveMovie(title: String): LiveData<List<Movies>> {
        return repository.retrieveMovie(title)
    }
}
```

Repository de room:

```
class MoviesRepository (private val moviesDao: MoviesDao) {

    val readAllData: LiveData<List<Movies>> = moviesDao.readALlData()

    fun addMovie(movie: Movies){
        moviesDao.addMovie(movie)
    }

    fun movieExists(id:Int){
        moviesDao.movieExists(id)
    }

    fun retrieveMovie(title:String): LiveData<List<Movies>> {
        return moviesDao.retrieveMovie(title)
    }
}
```

Dao:

```
package com.app.challengemovieapp.db

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.room.*
import com.app.challengemovieapp.model.Movie
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

@Dao
interface MoviesDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun addMovie(movie:Movies)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM movie_table ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun readALlData(): LiveData<List<Movies>>

    @Query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM movie_table WHERE id = :id)")
    fun movieExists(id : Int) : Boolean

    @Query("SELECT * FROM movie_table WHERE title = :title")
    fun retrieveMovie(title:String): LiveData<List<Movies>>

}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema exactamente? ¿Qué es `itemTextTitle`? ¿En algunos casos `retrieveMovie` podrá devolver varios objetos? Si no es así, ¿por qué declaras una lista y no un simple objeto?

Comment: En primer lugar si esperas recibir un único elemento, deberías reemplazar `List<Movies>` por `Movies` en el DAO. De todos modos lo que intentaste (`it[0].title`) debería funcionar. No lo hace porque, según el mensaje del error, la lista está vacía. Revisa el valor de `titleString` y asegurate que exista en tu base de datos.

Comment: Intenta usar el id de tu modelo, al usar el titulo, puede que tengas dos movies con el mismo titulo. Asimismo, si quieres obtener solo un objeto y no una lista, deberías tener algo como "fun retrieveMovie(title:String): LiveData<Movies>"